# Wording for survey questions

Tags: surveys

We currently use the terminology when asking a clients when in their session would they like survey questions for participants:

**Pre Questions** - before the session begins

**Post Questions** - after the session

**Pre and Post Questions** - using before and after questions

But I would like to make it much simpler into:

**Before**

**After**

**Both**

Is the single word option enough to describe exactly when those questions will appear?

Would prefer to use a single word, but open to other possibilities.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't up to the user/participant! It is your study,  just make sure you ask the right questions at the right time.

The questions you ask and when you ask them will have an effect on your results.  Plus you cannot have different procedures for different participants in the same study.

In answer to your question Pre/During/Post is fine

Comment: The session runner will be setting up the questions (if they want them), so it's up to them when if they want them to occur! Should have added that :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular requirement behind why you want it to be one word?

I think it would be more clear to use two words. (I'm imagining your question is something like "When would you like to display this survey?")

Your options can be:

- Before session
- After session

If you use checkboxes for the options, you can get rid of the third option of "both".